# Linq .Except behavior not as expected

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables: tableA and tableB, both have an attribute "CommissionNumber" which contains strings in the form of D123456789 (one letter followed by a fixed number of digits).

I need to find the commissionnumbers in table A, that are not in table B.

In SQL, this could look like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableA
  WHERE CommissionNumber NOT IN
  (
        select CommissionNumber from tableB
  )
```

Which gives me no results. However, if i try this:

```
var tableA= dbContext.tableA.Select(x => x.CommissionNumber).ToList();
var tableB= dbContext.tableB.Select(x => x.CommissionNumber).ToList();

IEnumerable<string> missingFiles = tableA.Except(tableB);
```

I get 92 hits. I don't understand what's wrong, my SQL query of the use of the .Except function.

Any ideas?

Comment: No whitespace, no case sensitivity mismatch?

Comment: You were on the right path. I found out that I had entries with a lower-case leading letter and it seems that SQL did not care for case sensitivity and recognized C12345 in tableB, when i was looking for c12345 from tableA. EF Core performed the search case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You have created two LINQ queries which retrieves all data from two tables into the memory and applied `Except`. It is wrong if you care about performance.

If you want to create SQL in the same way, LINQ query should be written accordingly. LINQ equivalent for `IN` operator is `Contains`.

```cs
var query = dbContext.tableA
    .Where(x => !dbContext.tableB.Select(b => b.CommissionNumber).Contains(x.CommissionNumber));
```

Or by `EXISTS` which have analogue `Any`

```cs
var query = dbContext.tableA
    .Where(x => !dbContext.tableB.Any(b => b.CommissionNumber == x.CommissionNumber));
```

Also the same result you can achieve by LEFT JOIN

```cs
var query = 
    from a in dbContext.tableA
    join b in dbContext.tableB on a.CommissionNumber equals b.CommissionNumber into gj
    from b in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where b.CommissionNumber == null
    select a;
```

Comment: Thank you for that insightful remark. I'd love to implement it that way but the dbContext of both tablesA and B isn't the same and that will lead me to the famous 'Cannot use multiple context instances within a single query execution. Ensure the query uses a single context instance.' error. Hope the EF core guys come up with a solution for that. I don't want to have the hustle of joining on DB level using a view so for the time being, I just leave it as is.

Comment: It is important part that you have used two different contexts. Well I have not more ideas instead of using third party libraries and temporary tables. Next time mention important things in question.

Answer (score 0):

gsharp was on the right track. I had some case sensitivity issues in my data which was ignored in the native SQL query but taken seriously by EF core.

Comment: Have you solved your problem by fixing [case sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity)?

Comment: EF core would have done it as you would expect it (in SQL). As soon as you call   .ToList() the Linq query is translated to SQL but afterwards EF core is done. What comes from that point on is  "normal" LINQ on Types... (where case sensitivity matters by default).